# Firebase firestore query: "Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here"

Tags: database, firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I have what I thought was a simple query on a collection called 'email':

```
 const emailQuery = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('email')
    .where('sendAt', '>=', new Date())
    .where('orderId', '==', doc.orderId)
    .where('brandId', '==', doc.brandId);
```

I'm receiving the error in the subject of this post, indicating that I need to create an index for this query. I've tried creating a couple for the relevant fields, but I'm unsure of why it's needed since only one field is ordered--and the error remains despite these indexes:

```
sendAt -> Ascending, brandId -> Ascending, orderId -> Ascending

sendAt -> Descending, brandId -> Ascending, orderId -> Ascending
```

I'm not specifying an `orderBy` as you can see. Also, `sendAt` is a date, while the other two are simple strings that don't need to be ordered.

What kind index do I need, or how do I get past this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing):

> If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map
> to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes
> a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.

To state it another way: when you use a comparison that involves `<` or `>`, there is an implicit ordering in the query on that field.  When used in combination with conditions on other fields, an index is required for the particular collection ID.

The error message that you started to quote in the title of your question should contain a link to the console that will create the required index for that query.  Just follow that link and authorize the creation of the index.

Comment: Thanks Doug. Understood, although I thought this would fall under the scope of the simple queries that Firebase reports should be covered with build-in indexes (the documentation link you provided doesn't work).

The error does include a link, although I have a few accounts on Firebase and the link seems to assume the wrong account. I can play with that a bit more I'm sure.

Comment: Link is fixed.  Simple queries are those that involve only a single field, or multiple fields on exact content match (no ranges).

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson you saved my time :)