# The query requires an index, but i already create the index

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I get the following error

> W/Firestore( 1034): (19.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(userChat
>   where to == M-00710 order by -messageDate, -**name**) failed:
>   Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an
>   index. You can create it here:
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/..., cause=null}

It happens when I am trying to find a `record`

```
 void getReply() {
    var userQuery = databaseReference
        .collection(documentId)
        .where('to', isEqualTo: userId)
        .orderBy("messageDate", descending: true)
        .limit(1);
    userQuery.snapshots().listen((data) {
      data.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
        print('documentChanges ${change.document.data}');
      });
    });
  }
```

This is my index

[image]

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase firestore query: "Error: 9 FAILED\_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216614/firebase-firestore-query-error-9-failed-precondition-the-query-requires-an-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you are using will need a composite index on "**to**" and "**messageDate**" field, but Index you have created seems to be on "**from**" and "**messageDate**" fields.

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite index on collection `userChat` like given below

```
messageDate:DESC  to:ASC
```