# Running where and orderby clause in firebase

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
const {orderBy, orderDir} = getOrderInfo(sortBy);

var query = exercisesRef;

if (category){
  const categoryField = 'categories.' + category;
  query = query.where(categoryField, '==', true);
}

if (equipment){
  query = query.where('equipments', 'array-contains', equipment);
}

if (search){
  query = query.where('metatags', 'array-contains', search);
}

if (collectionId){
  query = query.where('collections', 'array-contains', collectionId);
}

const snapshot = await query.orderBy(orderBy, orderDir)
                            .offset(perPage * (page - 1))
                            .limit(Number(perPage))
                            .get();
```

I've tried this code but It sends error message like this:
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. .....

But I don't want to create index manually.
How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216614/firebase-firestore-query-error-9-failed-precondition-the-query-requires-an-i

Is your goal to automate the process of creating an index?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automatically create an index.  You have to make an effort to define the required indexes one way or another.  There are two supported mechanisms that are relatively easy:

- You can [use the console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).
- You can use the [firestore.indexes.json config and deploy them with the CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/firestore/indexes).

Answer (score 0):

As Doug answered, the normal approach is to manually create the necessary index through the Firestore web console - either by clicking on the URL in the error message, or by navigating to the correct tab in the console yourself.

---

While it is **possible** to automatically create indexes, I wouldn't recommend it - I just wanted to show it for completeness: you can [deploy indexes through the Firebase CLI](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_cli), or [create indexes through Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/firestore_index). So if you're willing to somehow augment the indexes file or generate the correct Terraform definition, you could then auto-deploy it.

Of course, such operations only are possible for a user that has administrative access to your project, but since you tagged with `[node-js]` I assume you're running on a trusted environment already.